# Перебор массива foreach php

Tags: php

Пытаюсь перебрать массив:

```php
foreach ( $cums as $cum ) {
  $tag = $cum['service']['tag'];
  $text= array($tag);
}
```

Содержание $cums -

```
{"service":{"tag":{"de":"de","jo":"jo"},"name":{"de":"\ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea Quoka","jo":"\u0425\u0443\u0439\u043d\u044f"},"domain":{"de":"quoka-de","jo":"kdjfds-jo"}}}
```

Хочу получить данные de,jo

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Чтобы мы могли понять в чем ошибка - стоит описать желаемый результат при выполнении кода.

Comment: Хочу что бы он вывел значение de

Comment: @ya_uchu_js вы напрямую обращаетесь к нужным вас элементам массива. Зачем вы его вообще здесь перебираете?

Comment: там будет несколько значений, и надо перебирать

Comment: у вас json, а не массив, ничего не смущает? или вы из жыэс к нам пришли?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете разобрать ваш `JSON` следующим образом

```php
<?php

$str = '{
   "service":{
      "tag":{
         "de":"de",
         "jo":"jo"
      },
      "name":{
         "de":"\ud83c\udde9\ud83c\uddea Quoka",
         "jo":"\u0425\u0443\u0439\u043d\u044f"
      },
      "domain":{
         "de":"quoka-de",
         "jo":"kdjfds-jo"
      }
    }
}';

$data = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON string into an associative array

$de = array();
$jo = array();

foreach ($data['service'] as $key => $value) {
    $de[$key] = $value['de'];
    $jo[$key] = $value['jo'];
}

// output the results
print_r($de);
print_r($jo);

?>
```

[Вот реализация](https://onlinephp.io?s=bVFNa8JAEL0H8h8GCURBsVQLtVa999BSelSRITtqVs2m-yFI8b93dhMlpbm83XmPfTNv9nVR7ss4iqPEWA0zSH_iCAA6hvQ5z6jzUtWesrhrlJ4RrHvoN0mpmGS4cde72inwRG0WKyeeRxmjoEnjjvDp1AFb7FfuYfz45HE88jiaBBSB2ba1FuqEedHW_Nv3GLSmOAi5FWbQDFNd-Lim07A2gRZ5b9KoYiMoU4K6fpV9sNpRbwrDIVQ02D3B29fHO7CcFzvIC6sAC0BjVJajzc8EqDVeKl9i11B2e9wpkepPHUdbpQmzPXTDCMu0_rF0zYaQHOgCszkkZzzyGFDHZtell9bsVUnLVPCTaS1L9U-WKshX35KzKGdLZ0MWTcYdrYmjkuPYjeZByI92L6WqJl3MfwE%2C&v=8.2.1).